# OWN_TASK_FAILURE while running UDF in HIVE for custom deserialization.

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, udf

I'm writing a hive script to extract data from a source and add it to a different destination. The data stored in the source is in a custom format. Hence I'm using a Hive UDF to get the data, deserialize it and return a `List<String>` (I've tried `List<org.apache.hadoop.io.Text>`).

I created a Hive table (HIVE_TABLE) with 4 string parameters and run the following hive query.

```
> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE HIVE_TABLE SELECT udfFunction(colName)[0], udfFunction(colName)[1], udfFunction(colName)[2], udfFunction(colName)[3] from sourceTable;
```

where 'udfFunction' is my customFunction that returns `List<String>`, 'colName' stores the serialized data in sourceTable (another hive table).

Upon executing the above script, I get the following exception.

```
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 255 ]]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:0, Vertex vertex_1489044803200_0651_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0
```

Can someone explain when do we get the OWN_TASK_FAILURE exception and what is going wrong in the above strategy?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `mr` as the execution engine:

```
set hive.execution.engine=mr;
```

Sometimes it's hard to debug with `tez`.